pd.Grouper : TypeError: Period type does not support sum operations
after a long time im back to pandas and encountered an issue.
About a year ago i had it all working but stopped progressing and had other things to do and today decided to go back and try to run my tool.
source = rankdf.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1M',key='PuDate'), 'Driver']).sum().reset_index()

Used to work fine in the past and today i discovered i have an issue.
Gives me this error:
TypeError: Period type does not support sum operations

If i use:
source = rankdf.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M',key='PuDate'))['Driver'].sum().reset_index()

It gives me very different visual .
Previous code was ranking by months with altair map and later one just gives me straight line with everyone in it.
Have not touched pandas,python for a year so my memory is very rusty.
Thank You for your help!

If you just want to group by PuDate and Driver without summing Driver,
source = (rankdf.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1M', key='PuDate'), 'Driver'])
                 .sum(numeric_only=True)  # Sum only numeric columns
                 .reset_index())


Thank You! Worked like it should be. I read about numeric only but kinda have no clue where it had to go and now made all sense as after this issue new came in but adding same numeric_only=True solved another issue!
